# Can I change windowFlags outside of widget constructor?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

I am attempting to add a "Full Screen" option to my Qt (using PyQt) application. If the user hits F11, the goal is to maximize the window.

I am having problems removing the window title bar though. Normally, I'd do something like `self.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.CustomizeWindowHint)` in `__init__` and the title bar would not display (expected behavior). However, if I launch the Qt application, and then wait for the user to press F11 like so:

```
def keyPressEvent(self, event):
    if event.key() == QtCore.Qt.Key_F11:
        self.__doFullScreenCheck()

def __doFullScreenCheck(self):
    if self.maximizedFlg == False:
        self.__maximizeWindow()

def __maximizeWindow(self):
    ***self.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.CustomizeWindowHint)***
    screen = QtGui.QDesktopWidget().screenGeometry()
    self.setGeometry(screen)
    self.maximizedFlg = True
```

Having the marked line in `__maximizeWindow` outside of `__init__` seems to make the window completely vanish. The application is still running (seen in task manager), but I can't switch back to it using Alt+Tab or Task Manager.

How can I change Window Flags on fly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [Qt documentation on QWidget::windowFlags](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qwidget.html#windowFlags-prop):

> **Note**: This function calls `setParent()` when changing the flags for a window, causing the widget to be hidden. You must call `show()` to make the widget visible again.

So just add `self.show()` after `self.setWindowFlags(...)` and you'll be fine.

Comment: D'oh! I was reading that exact passage several times and missed that. Thanks for pointing out the obvious.